# Rewrite a PHP function with arrays instead

Tags: php, arrays, function

Is there any way I could rewrite this function with an array instead of all these if statements? Could i maybe use some for loop together with an array? How would that look like? Any suggestions of simpler code?

Here is my php function:

```
function to_next_level($point) {

    /*
    **********************************************************************
    *
    *   This function check how much points user has achievents and how much procent it is until next level
    *
    **********************************************************************
    */

    $firstlevel = "3000";
    $secondlevel = "7000";
    $thirdlevel = "15000";
    $forthlevel = "28000";
    $fifthlevel = "45000";
    $sixthlevel = "80000"; 

    if($point <= $firstlevel) {

        $total = ($point/$firstlevel) * 100;
        $remaining =  round($total);

        //echo number_format($remaining, 0, '.', ' ');
        return $remaining;

    } elseif ($point <= $secondlevel) {

        $total = ($point/$secondlevel) * 100;
        $remaining =  round($total);

        //echo number_format($remaining, 0, '.', ' ');
        return $remaining;
    } elseif ($point <= $thirdlevel) {

        $total = ($point/$thirdlevel) * 100;
        $remaining =  round($total);

        //echo number_format($remaining, 0, '.', ' ');
        return $remaining;
    } elseif ($point <= $forthlevel) {

        $total = ($point/$forthlevel) * 100;
        $remaining =  round($total);

        //echo number_format($remaining, 0, '.', ' ');
        return $remaining;
    } elseif ($point <= $fifthlevel) {

        $total = ($point/$fifthlevel) * 100;
        $remaining =  round($total);

        //echo number_format($remaining, 0, '.', ' ');
        return $remaining;
    } elseif ($point <= $sixthlevel) {

        $total = ($point/$sixthlevel) * 100;
        $remaining =  round($total);

        //echo number_format($remaining, 0, '.', ' ');
        return $remaining;
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the question here? You gave the answer yourself! Put those threshholds (the numbers) into an array and then iterate over that array. since all conditional branches are equal that should not be an issue. Why is the issue you cannot solve in that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function to_next_level($point) {

    /*
    **********************************************************************
    *
    *   This function check how much points user has achievents and how much procent it is until next level
    *
    **********************************************************************
    */

    $levelArray = array(3000, 7000, 15000, 28000, 45000, 80000);
    foreach ($levelArray as $level) 
    {
        if ($point <= $level) {
            $total = ($point/$level) * 100;
            $remaining =  round($total);  

            //echo number_format($remaining, 0, '.', ' ');
            return $remaining;            
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: the return statement will get executed on first iteration of the loop - should it not be at the end, outside the loop?

Comment: I have same answer too, I was hitting enter and then I saw your answer popped lol

Comment: @RamRaider What VMcreator said.

Comment: @vmcreateor - agreed !

Answer (score 2):

Start using OOP programming style. This is the perfect opportunity since it is a task without much complexity. Create a class that acts as central authority. That class can receive more methods over time. That way your code stays easy to maintain since all those functions are kept inside a class.

```
<?php

class levelAuthority
{
  public static $thresholds = [ 3000, 7000, 15000, 28000, 45000, 80000 ];

  public static function getDistanceToNextlevel($points)
  {
    foreach (self::$thresholds as $threshold) {
      if ($points <= $threshold) {
        $total = ($points/$threshold) * 100;
        $remaining =  round($total);
        return $remaining;
      }
    }
  }
}

// in the calling scope:
$points = 5000;
echo levelAuthority::getDistanceToNextlevel($points);
```

Answer (score 2):

lots of answers to this!!

here is mine using a while loop - single exit point outside the loop:

```
function to_next_level($point) {
    /*
    **********************************************************************
    *
    *   This function check how much points user has achievements and how much percent it is until next level
    *
    **********************************************************************
    */

    $arr_level = array(3000,15000,28000,45000,80000);
    $remaining = false;
    while (!$remaining and list($key,$level) = each($arr_level)) {
        if ($point <= $level) {
            $total = ($point/$level) * 100;
            $remaining = round($total);
        }
    }
    // will return false if $point is greater than highest value in $arr_level
    return $remaining;
}
```

Comment: best solution in my opinion, but you can make it even faster if you use current and next, instead of list and each: `while (!$remaining and ($level = current($arr_level) or next($arr_level)))`

Answer (score 1):

You could write an additional function, that does the calculations and trigger it from the if/else if/else blocks.

```
function calculate_remaining($points, $level) {
    $total = ($point/$level) * 100;
    $remaining =  round($total);
    return $remaining;
}
```

You'd trigger this like:

```
if($point <= $firstlevel) {
    return $calculate_remaining($point, $firstlevel);
} elseif ($point <= $secondlevel) {
    return $calculate_remaining($point, $secondlevel);
} etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
function to_next_level($point)
{
    $levels = array(
        3000,
        7000,
        15000,
        28000,
        45000,
        80000
    );

    foreach ($levels as $level)
    {
        if ($point <= $level)
        {
            $total = ($point / $level) * 100;
            $remaining =  round($total);

            //echo number_format($remaining, 0, '.', ' ');
            return $remaining;

        }
    }
}
```

The point levels are in order in the array, so `[0]` is `$firstlevel`, and so on. You simply iterate through the array and return whenever we reach the condition where `$point` is `<=` to the the `$level`.

Also, since `$levels` is static, it can be defined outside of the function.

Answer (score 1):

simple:

```
<?php
$point = 100;
$remaining = 0;
$data = [
    'firstlevel' => 3000,
    'secondlevel' => 7000,
    'thirdlevel' => 15000,
    'forthlevel' => 28000,
    'fifthlevel' => 45000,
    'sixthlevel' => 80000
];

foreach($data as $item)
{
    if($point <= $item)
    {
        $remaining = round(($point / $item ) * 100); //or return val
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about putting your variable into array and loop it?

```
  function to_next_level($point) {    
      $data[0] = "3000";
      $data[1] = "7000";
      $data[2] = "15000";
      $data[3] = "28000";
      $data[4] = "45000";
      $data[5] = "80000"; 
      foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
          if($point <= $value) {

          $total = ($point/$value) * 100;
          $remaining =  round($total);

          return $remaining;

    }
}
```

}

I haven't try it. But it might work for you.